# Minimum number of real multiplications to multiply two quaternions

Tags: algorithms

*Karatsuba multiplication* of two complex numbers can be performed with just three real multiplications (instead of four) as follows:
$$(a+bi)(c+di) = (ac-bd) + i ((a+b)(c+d) - ac-bd)$$
We only need the products $ac$, $bd$ and $(a+b)(c+d)$. Does there exists a similar trick for quaternion multiplication? A naive multiplication would need $16$. This can probably be reduce to $9$ using the same trick as above (and taking into account that quaternion multiplication is non-commutative). My question is it known that $9$ is the lower bound? If not, does there exist an algorithm, which does quaternion multiplications in less than $9$ real multiplications?

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222820/minimum-number-of-real-multiplications-to-multiply-two-quaternions

Comment: Indeed, word-for-word duplicate. 17762, you ought to have included a link to the other question at each site. But I do note that no answers were given at the other site.

Comment: ...though an apparently useful comment was given by a certain Gerry Myerson...

Comment: http://www.theworld.com/~sweetser/quaternions/ps/cornellcstr75-245.pdf claims magic number $8$.

Comment: Also cross-posted to Theoretical Computer Science: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/31251/8067

Comment: @Turbo, it seems to me that paper claims 8 for non-commutative coefficients, but only claims at least 7 for commutative. Since OP is interested in real multiplications, we're in the commutative case here, so I'm not sure 7 is ruled out.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for the reference on math.se. The paper by Turbo is useful and you are right that $7$ seems to be the conjectured lower bound over commutative rings.

Comment: @Turbo Since I am interested in real multiplications, the conjectured lower bound is $7$ (from the article you referenced).